# R Shiny: Make collapsible tabsetPanel

Tags: r, shiny, tabs, aggregate

Hi I feel like this should be simple but I can't find a solution anywhere.

In the code below I have made the navbarpage collapsible but can't find a way to achieve the same thing for a tabsetpanel so the app ends up looking messy on e.g. a mobile device.

```
library(shiny)


# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
    navbarPage("Hello",
        collapsible=T,
        tabPanel("a",
            tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                tabPanel("1"),
                tabPanel("2"),
                tabPanel("3"),
                tabPanel("4"),
                tabPanel("5"))),
        tabPanel("b"),
        tabPanel("c"),
        tabPanel("d"),
        tabPanel("e")
        )
    )

server <- function(session,input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [bootstrap-tabcollapse](https://github.com/flatlogic/bootstrap-tabcollapse) library. Download [the js file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flatlogic/bootstrap-tabcollapse/master/bootstrap-tabcollapse.js) and put it in the **www** subfolder.

```
library(shiny)

js <- "$(document).ready(function(){$('#tabset').tabCollapse();});"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(
      HTML(
        "a.js-tabcollapse-panel-heading {
           display: block;
           text-align: center;
        }"
      )
    ),
    tags$script(src = "bootstrap-tabcollapse.js"),
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  navbarPage("Hello",
             collapsible=T,
             tabPanel("a",
                      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                                  tabPanel("1", tags$p("hello")),
                                  tabPanel("2", tags$p("hi")),
                                  tabPanel("3"),
                                  tabPanel("4"),
                                  tabPanel("5"),
                                  id = "tabset")),
             tabPanel("b"),
             tabPanel("c"),
             tabPanel("d"),
             tabPanel("e")
  )
)

server <- function(session,input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks your clip looks like exactly what I want. Unfortunately when I add this to my app nothing changes and I don't know enough about javascript etc to figure out why. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @person Did you put the JavaScript file in the **www** subfolder of your app? Then that should work.

Comment: Yes I put it there and saved it as bootstrap-tabcollapse.js. I have other HTML tags that are functional, perhaps they are interfering, the trouble is the app runs fine and no error messages are given, it just doesn't do what it should. (If there are not other answers I will of course award you the points)

Comment: @person If you post a minimal app that reproduces the issue I could try to help.

Comment: can you check your browser whether the js-file is actually loaded? you can also include a `console.log("HELLO SO");` on top of the JS code and use the inspect -> console tab in your browser to check if its active